# Bigger exclamation mark

Tags: symbols

How do you make the exclamation mark to be as big as the bracket?
Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: can't you write: `$n!$ where $n=\frac{p-1}{2}$` ?

Comment: Have you considered using an inline fraction, i.e., writing `((p-1)/2)!`?

Comment: Or `(\tfrac{p - 1}{2})!`

Comment: Would you ask for a bigger “log“ in `\log\left(\frac{1+x}{x}\right)`? I guess you wouldn't. For the “factorial” operator it is exactly the same, apart from the position of the operator.

Comment: use the Γ-function

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

It can be done -- *but it shouldn't*.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for "\resizebox" macro
\newlength\mylen
\settoheight{\mylen}{$\bigg)$}
\newcommand\bigbang{\vcenter{\hbox{\resizebox{!}{1.6\mylen}{!}}}}
\begin{document}
\[ 
\Biggl( \biggl( \frac{p-1}{2}\biggr) \bigbang \Biggr) 
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: May I ask you why shouldn't it be done?

Comment: @TheMinhTran - Some adjectives I'd use to characterize the result of supersizing the exclamation mark: Ridiculous, preposterous, counterproductive, distracting, bizarre. Do you need more?

Comment: Have I then understood correctly, that in math papers they leave the exclamation mark the normal size? (that it doesn't depend on the size of the bracket in front of it?)

Comment: @TheMinhTran - I have obviously not read every single published math paper in existence.  That said, I've also *never* come across a paper that sported a humongous factorial symbol of the type shown in the answers Gustavo and I have provided. As I observed in an earlier comment, you should think seriously about using inline-fraction notation in these circumstances, i.e., write `((p-1)/2)!`. That way, there will never even a need to think about enlarging the factorial symbol.

Comment: Ok, Thanks a lot! (I am sorry if my questions seemed to be offensive to you, I really didn't mean to ;) )

Comment: @TheMinhTran - No worries -- no offense taken!

Answer (score 2):

The same result as Mico’s can be obtained with Steven B. Segletes’ `scalerel` package:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{amsmath} % unrelated, but always recommendable when math is involved
\usepackage{scalerel}



\begin{document}

Some text before the equation.
\[
    \Biggl(\biggl(\frac{p-1}{2}\biggr)
        % ( paren match
        \scalerel*{!}{\bigg)}\Biggr)
\]

\end{document}
```

(I was testing the code while Mico answered… :-)

**Edit:** I have corrected the code (it is `\scalerel*`, not `\scalerel`!), and I take the opportunity to show the output and to renew Mico’s recommendation (see comments… :-): ***don’t do it!***

[image: Output of the code]

**Addition:** I’ve been checking whether the result could look better if one uses `\stretchrel` instead of `\scalerel`, but I wouldn’t say so…

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{amsmath} % unrelated, but always recommendable when math is involved
\usepackage{scalerel}



\begin{document}

Some text before the equation.
\[
    \Biggl(\biggl(\frac{p-1}{2}\biggr)
        % ( paren match
        \scalerel*{!}{\bigg)}\Biggr)
\]

Perhaps better with \verb|\stretchrel|?
\[
    \Biggl(\biggl(\frac{p-1}{2}\biggr)
        % ( paren match
        \stretchrel*[500]{!}{\bigg)}\Biggr)
\]
I~wouldn't say so!

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output of the stretched example]